# Custom scheduler in Scala using Akka FSM does not respond to requests

Tags: scala, akka, state-machine, fsm

I was trying to write my own scheduler in Scala with help of Akka and FSM. The code shows no error. Here it is:

```
sealed private trait State

sealed private trait Data

private object Waiting extends State

private object Working extends State

private case object Start

sealed private case class TimedMessage(message: () => Unit, at: com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime)

private object Ping

sealed private case class MessageQueue(messages: Seq[TimedMessage]) extends Data

private object EmptyMessage extends Data

object ScalaScheduler {

  def apply(precision: Long) = new ScalaScheduler(precision)

}

class ScalaScheduler(precision: Long) {

  import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

  private val now = DateTime.now()
  private val system = ActorSystem("Scala-Scheduler-Actor-System")
  private val actor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SchedulerActor], precision).withDispatcher("redis-dispatcher").withMailbox("akka.actor.mailbox.redis"))

  def scheduleAfter(message: () => Unit, in: ScheduleUnit) = in match {
    case Months(time: Int) => actor ! TimedMessage(message, DateTime.now + time.months)
    case Days(time: Int) => actor ! TimedMessage(message, DateTime.now + time.days)
    case Hours(time: Int) => actor ! TimedMessage(message, DateTime.now + time.hours)
    case Minutes(time: Int) => actor ! TimedMessage(message, DateTime.now + time.minutes)
    case Seconds(time: Int) => actor ! TimedMessage(message, DateTime.now + time.seconds)
  }

}

sealed private class SchedulerActor(precision: Long) extends Actor with FSM[State, Data] {

  import scala.concurrent.blocking
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  startWith(Working, EmptyMessage)

  when(Waiting) {
    case Event(Start, EmptyMessage) =>
      println("At Waiting with Start and EmptyMessage")
      blocking(Thread.sleep(precision))
      goto(Working) using EmptyMessage
    case Event(Start, MessageQueue(messages)) =>
      println("At Waiting with Start and a message queue")
      blocking(Thread.sleep(precision))
      goto(Working) using MessageQueue(messages)
    case Event(message: TimedMessage, EmptyMessage) =>
      println("At Waiting with a message and EmptyMessage")
      blocking(Thread.sleep(precision))
      goto(Working) using EmptyMessage
    case Event(message: TimedMessage, MessageQueue(messages)) =>
      println("At Waiting with a message and a message queue")
      blocking(Thread.sleep(precision))
      goto(Working) using MessageQueue(messages ++ Seq(message))
    case Event(Ping, data: Data) =>
      println("At Waiting with Ping and EmptyMessage")
      blocking(Thread.sleep(precision))
      goto(Working) using data
  }

  when(Working, stateTimeout = 1 second) {
    case Event(TimedMessage(message, at), EmptyMessage) =>
      println("At Working with a message and EmptyMessage")
      if (Util compareTime at) {
        message()
        stay using EmptyMessage
      } else goto(Waiting) using MessageQueue(Seq(TimedMessage(message, at)))
    case Event(TimedMessage(message, at), MessageQueue(messages)) =>
      println("At Working with a message and a message queue")
      val (executable, waitable) = messages.partition(m => Util compareTime m.at)
      executable foreach (item => item.message())
      if (Util compareTime at) {
        message()
        goto(Waiting) using MessageQueue(waitable)
      } else {
        goto(Waiting) using MessageQueue(waitable ++ Seq(TimedMessage(message, at)))
      }
    case Event(StateTimeout, data: Data) =>
      println("At Waiting with StateTimeout")
      context.self ! Ping
      goto(Waiting) using data
  }

  initialize()

}

private object Util {

  import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

  def compareTime(at: DateTime) = at <= DateTime.now

}
```

Later, I tried running this in the REPL:

```
scala> val scheduler = ScalaScheduler(5000)
scheduler: com.socialcops.ScalaScheduler = com.socialcops.ScalaScheduler@1bbc4bc1

scala> val message = () => println("Hello, world!")
message: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> scheduler.scheduleAfter(message, Seconds(10))
```

Please note that I had imported the needed package where the above code is written.

However, it does not do anything.
This is an experimental project. I just want to impliment my own scheduler, it has nothing to do with using another scheduler.

What do you think could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?